# How to get the path of a running jar file OUTSIDE ide?

Tags: java

I have a javafx app that stores and edits data into a .xls file. I have a method that will create this .xls file unless it already exists. What I want to do is to create that .xls file in the same directory where the .jar file is located. I tried all the solutions around here for this and they work perfectly while running the project in eclipse ide but after I export the project and try to run the .jar file on my Desktop or on any other folder, nothing happens...

Comment: Instead of putting the new .xls file there, consider a more predictable location, like the user’s home directory or the user’s Documents directory.

Comment: I guess that sounds ok, but still, is it possible to do what I've asked ?

Comment: What you mean that nothing happens?When the .xls is in the same directory as your jar then the only you have to do is to use generally ("fileName.xls") in the path and it is working.

Comment: It is possible, but since [getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource() can return null](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html#getCodeSource--), it is not possible to do it *reliably.*  Even when the CodeSource is not null, CodeSource.getLocation() is only guaranteed to return a URL;  it is by no means guaranteed to return a file: URL.